# how to add different colors to multiple segments in a circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, path, fill

I have created a circle and divided it into 4 sections via the pen tool.

My problem is that I am unable to completely fill the 4 sections in 2 different colors. Section 1 & 3 need to be completely in green while section 2 & 4 completely in blue. Right now what I am getting is clear in the attached image. What is the best possible solution to add color as required? Adding screenshot of the layers I am using as well.

I started using illustrator 2 days ago and one of the first things I have learnt is the pen tool and how to create such a circle in it hence quite new to this tool and domain :)[image][image]

As per the first solution provided by WELZ I was able to get the desired color in segment 2 but 1,3 & 4 get colored by the same color when I want to add color to them individually as instructed in WELZ's solution.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason I'm adding another answer, is that this doesn't answer the question, but is a much simpler way to (*symmetrically*) create the shape you are making:

<sup>(This method would also avoid the issue in the first place)</sup>

---

1. Create your circle using the *Ellipse Tool*
2. Duplicate your circle and resize it to 50%
   <sub>Now create 4 clones of this smaller shape (Ctrl+C : Ctrl+F) **x4**</sub>
3. Move your 4 shapes 1 in each direction (to line up with the end of the bigger circle)
4. Select the shapes and use the shape builder tool to combine them by the dotted lines, so that it looks like;
5. *[Shape Builder Result]*
6. Change the shapes to desired color

[image]

### Update:

Since in my example I had the swirls running the opposite direction, here it is in the correct direction (just *join* them in the other direction - or if it's too late you can just reflect it)

[image]

Comment: Note: my shapes are (point) counter-clockwise, in your original it is clockwise, this can easily be fixed by either changing the lines you combine or if too late you can just use the reflect tool.

Comment: for a new comer like me this solution is much much better than your previous solution though that worked as well but I am going to go with this :) Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 5):

This is only a **direct** solution to the above mentioned problem, for a better way to create the shape, see [my other answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/103437/63979).

---

It seems that since your shapes aren't completed shapes, it's not filling it properly.

First use the *Divide tool* in pathfinder to break up and separate your shapes:

[image]

*Window* > *Pathfinder* (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**F9**</kbd>)

---

I would then use the shape builder tool (<kbd>Shift+M</kbd>)

Just Select all Objects (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and click and drag to connect (join) the shapes.

[image]

<sub>Note: You can use the *shape builder tool* in place for step 1. Just select all and *Click* each shape instead of *click+drag*</sub>

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question as I faced an issue while using your solution.

Comment: You can easily change the color (however you'd like) after you combine the shapes.

Comment: I divided the shapes as instructed but how do i combine the shapes?

Comment: actually found the error there was space between the anchor points in segment 1, 3 and 4 hence the error. Once I overlapped the points I was able to color them as per your solution :)

Comment: that GIF is quite satisfying...., upvoted for showing what the shape builder tool does